# REdeploying a file via feature makes SharePoint return two different “major” versions of a file

Tags: sharepoint-server

I created a feature with a module to deploy master page and a few additional JavaScript and CSS files. Deployed it first time -- everything was deployed well and worked as needed. But some time later I changed one of the CSS files and redeployed the feature (and reactivated, of course). And after that -- no changes of the CSS file on client, no matter how many times I cleared the browser cache.

After a very frustrating investigation I found out that SharePoint returned different versions of the CSS file:

1) When I click on ECB "download a copy" on the library item with the CSS file, SharePoint returns actual (latest) version of the file with all my edits.

2) When I open the CSS file display form (from ECB => "View properties") and just follow the file link of the CSS file on the display form, browser shows me the old version of a file. And this is the version that master page takes with its element and that is used by the browser:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="<%$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/EM_SPPR/css/elements.css%>" />
```

It's very strange and completely wrong. Please give an advice to where to dig further.

The file has published major version. The feature's elements.xml that contains module configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="Branding" Path="Branding" Url="_catalogs/masterpage/EM_SPPR">
        <File Type="GhostableInLibrary" Path="css\elements.css" Url="css/elements.css" Level="Published"  ReplaceContent="TRUE"  />
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Approval enabled on the masterpage library. If yes, you need to approve the page after publishing to get the latest version visible for non-admin users.

Comment: The problem is all that happens from under admin